# How to Get a Component to Re-render of Props Change (hooks)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've seen a few answers for the pre-hooks days, but haven't found anything for using useEffect.

I have an AJAX call that fires in the parent component to update a DB record, and when that comes back I setting state to the results of the new record from the database.

After the state is set I want to re-render the list of child components with the new list.

I thought useEffect was what I was looking for, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything in the child component

The code looks like

**RecipeEdit (parent component)**

```
const RecipeEdit = props => {

  const [ recipe, setRecipe ] = useState({})
  const [ instructions, setInstructions ] = useState(undefined)


  useEffect(() => {
    // used on first render
    fetchRecipeData()
  }, [])

 //AJAX call that I want to trigger a re-render of InstructionsEditList on completion
  async function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const body = { 
      recipe: {
        id: recipe.id,
        instructions_attributes: instructions
      }
    }

    fetch(`${API_ROOT}/api/recipes/${recipe.id}`, {
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      method: 'put',
      credentials: 'include',
      withCredentials: true,
      body: JSON.stringify(body)
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      if (data.status === 200){
        setIngredients(data.recipe_ingredients)
        setInstructions(data.instructions)
        //instructions which get passed down look fine here
        console.log(instructions)
      }
    });
  }


  const updateInstructionInInstructionsArray = (position, value) => {
    const tmp = instructions
    tmp[position].content = value
    setInstructions(tmp)
  };
```

**InstructionsEditList is the first child component & receives instructions prop from state**

```
  <InstructionsEditList instructions={instructions}
                        addElementToRecipeIngredientsOrInstructionsArray={addElementToRecipeIngredientsOrInstructionsArray}
                        removeInstructionFromInstructionsArray={removeInstructionFromInstructionsArray}
                        updateInstructionInInstructionsArray={updateInstructionInInstructionsArray}
  />

// InstructionsEditList and its child InstructionsEditItem are in the same file
// InstructionsEditItemList passes the instruction from RecipeEdit through itself to InstructionsEditItem (I don't believe InstructionsEditItem could be related to the issue)

  const InstructionsEditList = (props) => {

    useEffect(()=> {
      renderInstructionsItems()
    }, [props])
  
    // what I want to retrigger when props updates
    // in a console.log I can see props containing instructions and then going to undefined
    // after the ajax call, but not re-updating to the new array after the ajax completes

  const renderInstructionsItems = () => {
    if (props.instructions) {
      return props.instructions.map((instruction, index) => {
        return <InstructionsEditItem
                  key={index} 
                  position={index}
                  length={props.instructions.length}
                  instruction={instruction}
                  removeInstructionFromInstructionsArray={props.removeInstructionFromInstructionsArray}
                  updateInstructionInInstructionsArray={props.updateInstructionInInstructionsArray}
                />;
      });
    } else {
      return ""
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {renderInstructionsItems()}
    </div>
  )
}

export default InstructionsEditList;

const InstructionsEditItem = (props) => {

  return (
    <div className="mt-1 flex">
      <input
        required
        type="text"
        name="instruction"
        id="instruction"
        className="shadow-sm focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 block w-full sm:text-sm border-gray-300 rounded-md"
        defaultValue={props.instruction.content}
        onChange={(e) => props.updateInstructionInInstructionsArray(props.position, e.target.value)}
      />
      {maybeRenderDeleteIcon()}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: I think, you don't need to use `useEffect` in the child component to re-render. When state changes in parent component, react will re-render the affected child components.

Comment: @Tanvir that was my assumption too, and I actually didn't try the useEffect until after seeing the props update to undefined (re-render) then props are defined, but aren't passed down

Comment: Turns out I needed JSON.parse the response before setting state for some reason. After adding that it works as expected